# Unable to Start Beeswax Server for Hue-2.0.0-Beta

Tags: hadoop, hue

Unable to start the beeswax server due to Thrift dependency failer. Here is the failure log.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer.<init>(Lorg/apache/thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer$Args;)V
at com.cloudera.beeswax.Server.serveBeeswax(Server.java:203)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.Server.main(Server.java:159)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the version mismatch between the hue and the thrift plugins. I was testing Hue 2.0 beta with Hive 0.7. Hue 2.0 beta is compiled with Hive 0.8.

Please refer to the Issue here. https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-678